# Is it possible to make a Python script its own OS?

Tags: python, operating-system

I have written a Python script that I want to be able to run separately from the OS. As a result, I want it to be able to run as pretty much its own OS. Everything is shell based and there are no GUI components. How would I go about making a bootable version of this Python script, and is it even possible? Or would i have to put a bare-bones OS with the Python script installed as an addition?

Comment: How much time do you have?  In my opinion, Python lacks the kind of low-level features that are required to reasonably write a decent OS.  Find a very light version of Linux, and marry that with your Python script.

Comment: What does "run separately from the OS" even mean?

Comment: You'll need an OS to initialize and manage your hardware.  What's your python script going to do when the CPU gets an interrupt when a network packet comes in?

Comment: Wasn't there a project to get a Python-shell into GRUB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is theoretically possible to implement a stand-alone Python interpreter, which runs as the OS of a system. That has been done with several interpreter languages. First of all, BASIC, then APL, Forth, Smalltalk, Java, and most likely some I'm not aware of. There is no reason why this couldn't be done with Python, it merely needs a bit of implementation work.
To give a rough estimation of the amount of work:  a caffeine-driven expert coder takes about two days to implement a stand alone Forth interpreter, doubling as operating system, from scratch, on a platform (s)he's familiar with. By then the system will be far from finished or complete, but it will compile source, and allow extending itself with the results of that compilation. Other languages would differ. In case of Java, only porting an assembly implementation from one to an entirely different CPU took a team of 4 people about 2 weeks, while the back end of Java, the JVM, has a considerable resemblance to Forth. I'm not knowledgeable enough about Python inner workings to be able to give a meaningful estimate of the effort to implement a stand alone Python interpreter, but it could be roughly comparable to the effort of implementing a Java VM.

Comment: I forgot LISP in the list of interpreter implementations doubling as OS

Answer (score 3):

For all practical purposes, the answer is no, it's not possible. The bare-bones os with a python install is your best option.

Comment: Explain why.  Otherwise, this is just an unsubstantiated opinion.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: although you're technically correct, there are only new layers of opinions below this. Like, for example, that Python lacks the kind of low-level features needed to write a decent OS. I cannot even start to give a reasonable explanation of why the answer is no - as you very well know.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've never heard of a self-booting python port and can't think of any general purpose scripting languages that don't depend on an OS. I just don't see how we get to "unsubstantiated opinion" on this one.

Comment: @tdelaney That sounds like an explanation to me.